# How to display a div which is a value in my array of objects and embed it into a html page

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, user-interface

I have this array

```
        "videos": [
            {
                "title": "0-1 \u00c1ngel Zald\u00edvar",
                "embed": "<div style='width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:56.250%;'><iframe src='https:\/\/www.scorebat.com\/embed\/v\/61860cae4badd\/?utm_source=api&utm_medium=video&utm_campaign=v3' frameborder='0' width='100%' height='100%' allowfullscreen allow='autoplay; fullscreen' style='width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;'><\/iframe><\/div>"
            }
        ]
```

I'm using angular and i want to access the embeded div which has a video.
I've done this

```
<div *ngFor="let result of data.videos">
 <p> {{result.embed}} </p>
```

All i'm in the browser is a div tag instead of an embeded video.
Can someone help please

Here is my app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {stringfiedData:any;public data:any=[]constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}getData(){const url ='myApiUrl' this.http.get(url).subscribe((res)=>{this.stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(res);this.data = JSON.parse(this.stringifiedData);console.log(this.data)})}}
```

I have parsed the JSON data as suggested by @BrunoElo but still i get only the title but not the video even after applying the

```
 <p [innerHTML]="result.embed"></p>
```

Comment: Can you try: <p [innerHTML]="result.embed"></p>

Comment: I've tried this and i'm not getting any result in the browser

Comment: I might be wrong but maybe this data is in JSON form so you need to parse it to object first using `JSON.parse(<your array of data>)` before the property binding with `innerHTML`

Comment: No , I've added some details to my questions .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the [2nd answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding) would solve your problem, but I guess it's a bit different

Note: don't stringify or parse the response, it will already have been parsed by the HttpClient

```html
<div [innerHTML]="result.embed | safeHtml"></div>
```

Create the following pipe - and remember to add it to the module `declarations` and `exports` fields (or add it to a shared module)

```js
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(value: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

**Security:** only use this if you really do trust the source of the embed data, otherwise you leave yourself and your app open to XSS attacks